# Convert binary to hex value (32 bits)

Tags: c++, binary, hex

i am trying to convert binary value as hex value and i got the following code and it is working well up to 28 bit but not for 32 bit.

The code is as follows.

```
int main()
{
    long int longint=0;
    string buf;
    cin>>buf;
    int len=buf.size();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        longint+=( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i);
    }
    cout<<setbase(16);
    cout<<longint;
    return 0;
}
```

If I input 28 '1' (111111111111111111111111) then the output is fffffff
but if i input 32 '1' (11111111111111111111111111111111) then the output is 80000000.

Can anyone please explain why this is happenning  and also in the above code why 48 is subtracted .

Comment: what is this `48`?  Are you assuming ASCII?  You're probably better off with `'0'`.

Comment: which version of compiler do you use. try to find out the size of long it, if it's 32 bit , the first bit is the sign bit. Also try to use unsigned long int for longint

Comment: unsigned long int did the trick .. thank you ..:).. but it is coming as an small letter 'af' whereas it should be capital 'AF'.

Comment: use std::cout<<ios::uppercase before outputting the numbers

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the use of `pow`, which uses floating-point math, if I recall correctly..  You may be running into issues with overflow.

A more elegant way to calculate powers of two is by using bit-shifts:

```
2^0 = 1 << 0 = 1
2^1 = 1 << 1 = 2
2^2 = 1 << 2 = 4
2^n = 1 << n
```

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan's post, it'll display correct when changing your code like this,

```
longint += (buf[len-i-1]-'0') << i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using int32 and it is getting out of range when you use it for 32 bytes,try using int64 i.e long long

```
    unsigned long long longint=0; //Change Here
    string buf;
    cin>>buf;
    int len=buf.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        longint+=( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i);
    }
    cout<<setbase(16);
    cout<<longint;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is because you have forced 
   `( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i)`
    to be converted to **double**, 
   <strike>and **double** is 8 bytes long, 
   but it has to store extra information, 
   it can not be full charged to represent 0x80000000, 
   you can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 

    and your last 
   `( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i)` 
   (when i is 31) expression already **overflow**.</strike> 

   **But something weard happend when converting from 4294967295.0000000(which is 0xffffffff) to int , it just come out 0x80000000**  , but I am very sorry I don't know why（Please reference the comment from TonyK）.

   You can change it to

   longint+=(long int)(( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow(2,i));
2. Why minus 48 ? 
   because ascii for '0' is 48, you want to convert from literal '0' to numeric 0, you have to do it.

Comment: An IEEE double has a 53-bit mantissa, which is more than enough to store 0x80000000 to full precision.

Comment: You are right, the real problem is if I convert 4294967295.0000000 (which is actually 0xffffffff) to int, it just come out 0x80000000, And this part is out of my understanding

Comment: 0xffffffff is out of range for a 32-bit signed int. If you convert it to _unsigned_ int, you should get 0xffffffff.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that float-value is with limit precision and pow() computer use  numerical calculation approximation which isn't definitely precise. To get a precise value, you should use bit-wise ">>" instead.

You can see how pow() function works as below.

I changed your code

> longint+= ( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i)

to the code below, which is equal, becase pow() return a double value.

```
double temp = ( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i);
longint+= temp;
cout<<setbase(16);
cout<<"temp"<<endl;
cout<<temp<<endl;
cout<<longint<<endl;
```

the output is as below

```
temp
1.34218e+08
fffffff
temp
2.68435e+08
1fffffff
temp
5.36871e+08
3fffffff
temp
1.07374e+09
7fffffff
temp
2.14748e+09
80000000
final
80000000
```

Which shows clearly pow() is with limited precision. `2.14748e+09` is not equal to (2^31).

You should use ">>" which is the best or just use conversion to integer which isn't 100 percently correclty, either.

You can see conversion as below.

when I change

> double temp = ( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i);

to

> int temp = ( buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow((double)2,i);

the result is

```
temp
8000000
fffffff
temp
10000000
1fffffff
temp
20000000
3fffffff
temp
40000000
7fffffff
temp
80000000
ffffffff
final
ffffffff
```

Which works correctly.

**substract 48**
You got a char from standard input, for example, you got '1' from terminal instead of 1. In order to get 1. You should use '1'-'0'. 
The reason : computer store '0'～'9' as a byte with value（48～57）. As a result， '1' - '0' equals '1' - 48.